# Function not passed as a function

Tags: javascript, three.js, anonymous-function

I'm working on a short 'Engine' class to somewhat simplify interactions with Three.js.  I refactored the example's Render() method to this Engine JS class, as below:

```
var Engine = function () {
  var pub = {},
      scene,
      camera;

  // SNIP: Extra private and public variables and functions...

  pub.Render = function (fixedUpdate) {
    requestAnimationFrame(pub.Render);
    fixedUpdate();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };

  return pub;
}();
```

I attempt to use it by passing some function with actions that I want to perform to it.  For example:

```
Engine.Render(function () {
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.02;
});
```

When I attempt to run this in Chrome, however, I get the error: *Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function*, and upon inspecting Engine.Render's fixedUpdate variable, it's usually some extremely large number, and apparently not registering as the anonymous function that the calling code passed in.

As a sanity test, I attempted passing the handle to a non-anonymous function, like such:

```
function animation() {
  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.02;
}

Engine.Render(animation);
```

...and got exactly the same result.  I suspect the problem lies in how I am calling the parameter.

Comment: The large number is a timestamp, passed to the callback of `requestAnimationFrame` when it runs. Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942722/typeerror-canvas-getcontext-is-not-a-function/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
  pub.Render = function (fixedUpdate) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {pub.Render();});
    fixedUpdate();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };
```

Comment: Don't you mean `function () {pub.Render()}`? :-P

Comment: Got rid of the error, but no animation is occurring now.  However, this is probably due in part to how I'm defining the call-forward, and thus is out of the scope of this question.  The error is gone!

Comment: Maybe `requestAnimationFrame(function () {pub.Render(fixedUpdate);});` ?